# Simple Drupal hook_menu

Tags: hooks, routes

I would like to pass data from Javascript to PHP using Drupal 7.14.  To this end, I'm trying to follow this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834132/how-to-pass-jquery-variable-to-drupal-ajax.

However, |hook_menu()` is not working as expected.

```
function example_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['example_callback/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Custom Callback', 
    'description' => 'Description', 
    'page callback' => 'my_custom_php_function', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), // fill this
    // 'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'access callback' => true,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Function that gets called from JQuery asynchronously. 
 */
function my_custom_php_function($argument) {
  // Do something with $argument...
  echo $argument;   
}
```

In my understanding, going to http://mywebsite.com/example_callback should call my_custom_php_function.  Instead, I get:

> The requested URL /example_callback was not found on this server.

Are there other steps necessary to write a simple menu callback?

Comment: Menu items are cached, so make sure you clear the cache by going to Administer -> Performance.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is expecting an argument so your URL would have to be  http://mywebsite.com/example_callback/something. I wouldn't bother with the extra % in the path though.

So you should be doing something like and it will still pick up the arguments:

```
function example_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['example_callback'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Custom Callback',
    'page callback' => 'my_custom_php_function',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );

 return $items;
}

/**
* Function that gets called from JQuery asynchronously. 
*/
function my_custom_php_function() {
  if (arg(1)) {
    // this means there is an argument
    // Do something with $argument...
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: Try the above again, but add a return;

Comment: Still receiving a 404 error when I navigate to http://myexample.com/example_callback/something. Two follow-up questions:  1) Am I supposed to write something else for the above hook to work, e.g. a .install file?   2) Do I have to create a new page, e.g. example_callback.php?

Comment: `return $items;` does not fix the problem.

Comment: No to both questions, you just need the menu item in hook_menu() and the callback function. I meant you should add a return in the page callback.

Comment: I've just tried the above at it works perfectly my end. Are you placing this in a module called 'example_module'?

Comment: I placed this code in example_module.module inside a folder called example_module. full path to module is sites/all/modules/example_module/example_module.module

Comment: This might seem naive, but how exactly am I supposed to "invoke" or activate the callback?

Comment: When you clear the cache Drupal rebuilds the menu router and stores the data in the menu_router table. This is where page callbacks are mapped to paths. So Drupal takes care of invoking that function when a page is requested. I would look at the examples module, if you haven't already, there's lots of good comments in there explaining everything. http://drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: You don't have to return anything. For a nice and simple example, check out [user_autocomplete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_autocomplete/7). Also note how it uses [drupal_json_output()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) to return a json object.

Comment: The poster does not want to return anything though, drupal_json_output() is not required and user_autocomplete() returns an array of results to JS. I don't think there is anything wrong with returning an empty string, in this case.